# How do I open an image using Python?

Tags: python, image, tkinter

So, I was making a Python 3 program and I wanted to print the README file (I have both `.txt` and `.md`), and I thought it would be a good idea to first try opening an image. I used a code that I got off the internet:

```
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
im = Image.open("my image here") # not actually "my image here" but something different

#show image
im.show()


import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

root.attributes('-fullscreen',True)
```

and I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Hyper/Desktop/HyperShell/resources/ImageOpener.py", line 1, in <module>
    from PIL import ImageTk, Image
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
```

Any other ways to open images or print/open files?

I tried to use other tutorials, and I expected them to work but I still got errors.

Comment: `PIL` doesn't come with Python installation package, it isn't included in the Python standard library. You have to run `pip install PIL` first. And the problem is so trivial even the useless Google search can find you the right answer. You didn't even try Googling first...

Comment: Just to add on @ΞένηΓήινος's comment: While the import command is `import PIL` or `from PIL import ...`, the actual package name on PyPI is `Pillow`. So you need to run `pip install Pillow` (`pip install pillow` should also work) – same for installation via `conda`, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is just to display an image, and if the image is png or gif, you can use tkinter without PIL.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
image = tk.PhotoImage(file="/tmp/image.png")
label = tk.Label(root, image=image)
label.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

root.mainloop()
```

If you want to display other formats you'll need to use the PIL module, which requires you to install it.  The error in your question is related to the fact that you don't have the PIL module installed.

To install the PIL module, use the following command:

```
python -m pip install pillow
```